# Is it possible to run multiple robot framework in an interactive scenario?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I have a question about is it possible to run multiple robot framework in an interactive scenario?

For instance, if robot framework A running on computer A, robot framework B running on computer B, robot framework C running on computer C.

I want an scenario that A can send a message to B, and after B received the message from A, B will send another message to C, and after C received the message from B, C will send an ACK to A. Is it possible on robot framework? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What type of message are you talking about?

Comment: Hi @Rao, like type of REST including data as JSON.

Comment: Is the idea of running parallel execution?

Comment: Hi @Rao, yes. A topology is like A want to send message to C, so first A send to B(server), B then forward the message to C, and C ack back.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, could you provide some information about how to achieve it? Thank you!